# Regex parsing for specific pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a huge logfile to parse through with PHP that looks for something like this (please note that variables that are variable will be labelled):

```
16:09:47.925 T#10648 PresenceManager: à¿šnoticing[specialchar]$name[specialchar]0x8fac711e4bf14e62-d-s111.221.74.46:40022-r[IP]:48914-l192.168.1.2:48914f2812a403bdc6ade
```

I want to be able to look for this line that contains $name, then parse out the [IP] part, which is an IP. Please note there's two special char places which I have marked that cannot be shown in the post.

This is what I have:

```
if(preg_match('/' . $name . '*?-r(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/', $contents, $results))
```

However it doesn't seem to be finding the given ip like above D:

Pastebinny:: http://pastebin.com/YHh4fndP

$log = https://mega.co.nz/#!Scc11A6K!RXziJU_Ii43o1gcQetEfS7Kfzt-bY7VTJXljpCS7Gfc (username is sliceteam)

Thanks!

Comment: Working on it now, sorry but I'm a little confused by _"two special char places which I have marked that cannot be shown in the post"_.

Comment: It's hard to explain, the characters are a failure of decoding the message :3, couldn't something with the "dot" be used in its stead?

Comment: One more question, can you say what you consider the "IP" in your given example?  Do you want the `111.221.74.46` string (i.e. the first set of 4 digits) or do you want the string after `[IP]:`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the 111 ip also changes, but is not the same as the [IP], I want to capture [IP]. The 111 changes, so you may need to develop the regex for this bit too, as it is not the same. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want to just capture the data after [IP] if the string contains data from a `$name` variable? Can we assume that the string [IP] will only exist once on the line or that it's always the last instance?

Comment: No, I want to capture THE [IP], which is a valid IP address. I need to find the line within this text file containing $name, and then the [IP] within that line, and echo the [IP].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand how the IP is found, try this [regex](http://regex101.com/r/eX0rE8):

```
/(?:variable.*?-r)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/
```

`variable` is obviously where you would include the `$name` variable.  This uses a non capturing group to look for `variable` followed by any characters up to `-r` (the IP's preceder), and then capture an IP-like string.  I defined an IP as 3 sets of 1-3 digits followed by a period followed by one final set of 1-3 digits.

I hate to say it, but it seems like there is a different error in your script.  I narrowed your code down to:

```
<?php
$name = 'sliceteam';
$log = (array_pop(glob('debug-20140405-1732.log')));
$contents = file_get_contents($log);
if (preg_match_all("/(?:$name.*?-r)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/", $contents, $results))
{
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'success' => $results[1]));
}
?>
```

And it returned `{"status":"success","success":["168.62.23.92","213.146.168.254"]}` (which seems pretty damn right to me ;)`). What do you receive when you run the entire script..and I can try to debug the problem with you.

Comment: Uhm, I'm sorry for not specifying properly. T_T. I didn't explain this well in the OP. I replaced a real ip address as [IP], the [IP] isn't the actual string I wanted to get out, it represents a valid ip address.

Comment: @user3500524, that makes sense, my bad for not realizing. A quick question, I see the string `111.221.74.46` between `$name` and `[IP]` in your example..how do I know that that isn't the IP (it looks like an IP to me)?  In other words, I think we need to specify some more rules before I can right that regex.

Comment: This IP is different from [IP], it is also different, so you might need to regex an ip in this area. Here's a complete example:

16:09:47.925 T#10648 PresenceManager: à¿šnoticing[special]$name[special]0x8fac711e4bf14e62-d-s111.221.74.46:40022-r1.1.1.1:48914-l192.168.1.2:48914f2812a403bdc6ade

Comment: Oh, now I see the pattern! It is always after the `-r`, @user3500524?

Comment: No problem, describing regular expression rules is literally almost as hard as writing the regular expression itself @user3500524. Try my latest update and let me know how it goes.

Comment: If this how I'd write it?
if(preg_match_all('/(?:$name.*?-r)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/', $contents, $results))

I'm not quite sure where the ' go D: I'm a noob at regex. Can never understand it.

Comment: @user3500524 you would want to wrap the expression in double quotes (`"`) so that the variable is actually parsed instead of looking for `$name` literally. See: http://ideone.com/s6hitA

Comment: As a heads up, your last issue had to do with PHP's string parsing not regular expressions..so its worth reading up (for the benefit of future knowledge): [`The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Aaaaaaah - having read through the comments here - I now actually understand what you're after! Probably simplest if I just remove my answer as this one has gotta be pretty close now...

Comment: Took me a while too @CD001, I think its a combination of the scenario and the Jim Beam.

Comment: Uhm, I just applied what you asked for, but my json is still returning an error. It can't find the IP within the text file D:

Comment: @Sam Jim Beam and RegExp ... that can't be a good **match!** (baduuum tssssssss) .... sorry ;)

Comment: Can you update your question with your PHP in question and a [Pastebin](pastebin.com) of the JSON?

Comment: Updated OP with pastebin!

Comment: @user3500524 can you also upload the `$log` and perhaps give your test example of what `$name` equals? Things seem to be working when [I test](http://ideone.com/wq4R4D). And lol, @CD001!

Comment: Heh - this is where I got to on refiddle.com : http://refiddle.com/hhn - make of it what you will ;)

Comment: Alright, I'm going to upload the actual log, please open it in Notepad++ to see the special chars, I won't be able to copy it properly. The Log contains a lot of crap I don't need xD. The username in this example is "sliceteam"
https://mega.co.nz/#!Scc11A6K!RXziJU_Ii43o1gcQetEfS7Kfzt-bY7VTJXljpCS7Gfc

Comment: Also, as a side note, if there was a likely-common mistake made in your log/PHP..it may be worth noting (in OP) so that others that come know what finally worked.  If it was a blatant error, nevermind and have a good one :)